# Deploy Eclipse Che v7 on kubernetes cluster (not minikube)

Tags: eclipse-che

I have been reading Che's documentation and trying to figure out how to deploy it to a Kubernetes cluster (not minishift or minikube).

I tried to use [chectl](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/che-quick-starts.html) for this but it seems that only minikube or minishift are supported for now.

```sh
chectl server:start -m -n che
  ❯ ✈️  Minikube preflight checklist
    ✔ Verify if kubectl is installed
    ✖ Verify if minikube is installed
      → E_REQUISITE_NOT_FOUND
      Verify if minikube is running
      Start minikube
      Verify if minikube ingress addon is enabled
      Enable minikube ingress addon
      Retrieving minikube IP and domain for ingress URLs
 ›   Error: E_REQUISITE_NOT_FOUND
```

Is there any way that I can deploy eclipse che to a kuberntes cluster (not minikube or minishift)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the time being supported platforms are:

```
 [default: minikube] Type of Kubernetes platform. Valid values are "minikube", "minishift", "k8s", "openshift", "microk8s".
```

Have a look at the docs of the [chectl](https://github.com/che-incubator/chectl) repository.
For your case you need to try:

```
chectl server:start -m -n che --platform=k8s
```